# Is there a way to combine all of my queries into one using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to query multiple rows from one table in my database at once to extract a data value based on some parameters.

Like this

```
       const ele = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findOne({
                where: {
                    project_id,
                    commodity: 'ELE',
                    phase: 'predicted'
                }
            });
            const stm = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findOne({
                where: {
                    project_id,
                    commodity: 'STM',
                    phase: 'predicted'
                }
            });
            const hhw = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findOne({
                where: {
                    project_id,
                    commodity: 'HHW',
                    phase: 'predicted'
                }
            });
            const gas = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findOne({
                where: {
                    project_id,
                    commodity: 'GAS',
                    phase: 'predicted'
                }
            });
            const water = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findOne({
                where: {
                    project_id,
                    commodity: 'WTR',
                    phase: 'predicted'
                }
            });
            const peakchw = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findOne({
                where: {
                    project_id,
                    commodity: 'peak_CHW',
                    phase: 'predicted'
                }
            });
            const labor = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findOne({
                where: {
                    project_id,
                    commodity: 'labor',
                    phase: 'predicted'
                }
            });

  return res.render('predicted', {
                chw,
                ele,
                stm,
                hhw,
                gas,
                water,
                peakchw,
                labor,
```

I'm querying each one individually because each commodity is a different row and each commodity has a value that I need to pull out. I query each one individually because sometimes a commodity wont have a value (savings_percent) like for this project ID which only has values for commodities, CHW, ELE, STM, peack_CHW :

```
Prjt_source_percent_each {
    dataValues: {
      project_id: 'ADH 2018 EBCx',
      phase: 'predicted',
      commodity: 'CHW',
      savings_percent: 0.07456508908031056
    }
  },
  Prjt_source_percent_each {
    dataValues: {
      project_id: 'ADH 2018 EBCx',
      phase: 'predicted',
      commodity: 'ELE',
      savings_percent: 0.03188519669899027
    }
  },
  Prjt_source_percent_each {
    dataValues: {
      project_id: 'ADH 2018 EBCx',
      phase: 'predicted',
      commodity: peack_CHW
      savings_percent: 0.12195121951219512
    }
  },
  Prjt_source_percent_each {
    dataValues: {
      project_id: 'ADH 2018 EBCx',
      phase: 'predicted',
      commodity: 'STM',
      savings_percent: 0.14962427856611382
    }
]
```

Then in the HTML I take each variable and assign the savings_percent value to it corresponding place in the table.

```
             <table class="table text-light text-end">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th scope="col">CHW</th>
                        <th scope="col">ELE</th>
                        <th scope="col">STM</th>
                        <th scope="col">HHW</th>
                        <th scope="col">GAS</th>
                        <th scope="col">Dom Water</th>
                        <th scope="col">Peak CHW</th>
                        <th scope="col">Maintenance</th>
                        <th scope="col">Total</th>
                        <th scope="col">Miscellaneous</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ann Cash Flow</th>
                        <th scope="col">Payback</th>
                        <th scope="col">NPV</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="text-end">
                    <tr id="decimal">
                        <th scope="row">%</th>
                        {{#with chw}}
                        <td class="rounded">{{savings_percent}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                            <td></td>
                            {{/with}}
                        {{#with ele}}
                        <td class="rounded">{{savings_percent}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                            <td></td>
                            {{/with}}
                        {{#with stm}}
                            <td class="rounded">{{savings_percent}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                            <td></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with hhw}}
                            <td class="rounded">{{savings_percent}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                            <td></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with gas}}
                            <td class="rounded">{{savings_percent}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                            <td></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with water}}
                            <td class="rounded">{{savings_percent}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                            <td></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with peakchw}}
                            <td class="rounded">{{savings_percent}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                            <td></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with labor}}
                            <td class="rounded">{{savings_percent}}</td>
                            {{else}}
                            <td></td>
                        {{/with}}
                        {{#with percentTotal}}
                        <td class="rounded">{{percent_total}}</td>
                        {{/with}}
                    </tr>
                 </table>
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to combine all of those queries into one query and still have it operate the same way when I place the values into the HTML. I was thinking maybe I could create an array with the commodities and then iterate over that array but I'm not sure how to start that. Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can use `[Op.in]: ['ELE', 'STM', ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the follwing query:

```js
import { Op } from "sequelize";

...
...

const response = await Prjt_source_percent_each.findAll({
    where: {
        project_id,
        commodity: {
            [Op.in]: ['ELE', ...]
        },
        phase: 'predicted'
     }
});
```